# What does "in the tone of someone explaining that one and one made two" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "My dear young man, the Minister of Magic wouldn't have taken Hagrid if he hadn't been one hundred per cent sure that he was guilty," said Lockhart, ***in the tone of someone explaining that one and one made two***.

What does the phrase mean in this context?

-- From Harry Potter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"1+1=2" is a *rudimentary* concept, which (some feel) should be completely obvious. If you actually had to explain this concept, you might choose to speak in a *condescending* tone, as if the listeners were very small children, or otherwise extremely naive.

So this expression is a figurative metaphor for Lockhart's *pedantic* demeanor when justifying the Ministry of Magic's punishment of Hagrid.

Although I've heard this expression before, I wouldn't call it a "common" English idiom.  It's just a figure of speech that could be expressed in many different ways.  A similar example:

> "Yes, of course our President knows what he's doing," her uncle replied peevishly, **as if explaining that "the sky is blue" or "water is wet"**.  "If he wasn't competent, he wouldn't have been elected."