# Is "add two and two" an idiom?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms, etymology

> "Somebody Stupefied a Death Eater on top of the Tower after Dumbledore died. There were also two broomsticks up there. The Ministry can **add two and two**, Harry."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sub>

I deduce that "add two and two" is a variant of *[put two and two together](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+two+and+two+together)*. If so, any reason why it's been "two and two", not "one and one", etc. "One and one" looks more simple.

Comment: I think "two and two" is used as it's just generally considered the easiest non trivial sum. Similar to the phrase [when 2 + 2 = 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_%2B_2_%3D_5 "Wiki")

Comment: What @Bee said. To my mind, to be *able to **add two and two*** (or to *know **two and two make four***) - plus the pejorative negated versions (***not*** to be able to do the trivial sum) would be the "original" forms. Being able to ***put two and two together*** is a later derived "idiomatic" usage (that actually usually refers specifically to drawing conclusions from ***two single things*** both occurring, not two *pairs* of things).

Comment: ...compare also ***He knows [how many beans make five](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22how+many+beans+make+five%22)*** (he's not a *complete* idiot; in fact, he might be reasonably smart). But all such expressions are inherently "slangy", and may vary across different (geographical or social) linguistic subsets of the worldwide Anglophone population.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184807/what-does-in-the-tone-of-someone-explaining-that-one-and-one-made-two-mean